# Creating self-signed certificate using pyopenssl

Tags: python-2.7, openssl, x509certificate, self-signed, pyopenssl

I am trying to generate ac self signed X509v3 CA certificate using pyopenssl.
I would want to add the extension authority key identifier (AKID) with keyid containing subject key identifier (SKID).

But my following code block does not copy the SKID to AKID rather throws an exception.

The code is as follows

```
import OpenSSL

key = OpenSSL.crypto.PKey()
key.generate_key(OpenSSL.crypto.TYPE_RSA, 2048)

ca = OpenSSL.crypto.X509()
ca.set_version(2)
ca.set_serial_number(1)
ca.get_subject().CN = "ca.example.com"
ca.gmtime_adj_notBefore(0)
ca.gmtime_adj_notAfter(24 * 60 * 60)
ca.set_issuer(ca.get_subject())
ca.set_pubkey(key)
ca.add_extensions([
  OpenSSL.crypto.X509Extension("basicConstraints", True,
                               "CA:TRUE, pathlen:0"),
  OpenSSL.crypto.X509Extension("keyUsage", True,
                               "keyCertSign, cRLSign"),
  OpenSSL.crypto.X509Extension("subjectKeyIdentifier", False, "hash",
                               subject=ca),
  OpenSSL.crypto.X509Extension("authorityKeyIdentifier", False, "keyid:always",issuer=ca)
  ])
ca.sign(key, "sha1")
open("MyCertificate.crt.bin", "wb").write(
            OpenSSL.crypto.dump_certificate(OpenSSL.crypto.FILETYPE_ASN1, ca))
```

the Exception thrown is as follows

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Desktop\Certificate\certi.py", line 21, in <module>
    OpenSSL.crypto.X509Extension("authorityKeyIdentifier", False, "keyid:always",issuer=ca)
Error: [('X509 V3 routines', 'V2I_AUTHORITY_KEYID', 'unable to get issuer keyid'), ('X509 V3 routines', 'X509V3_EXT_nconf', 'error in extension')]
```

Now if I remove "**always**" from the line keyid parameter in the below line of the code

> OpenSSL.crypto.X509Extension("authorityKeyIdentifier", False,
>   "keyid",issuer=ca)

i get the AKID keyid field to be empty and it does not contain the SKID as shown below

```
          00:84:13:70:73:fe:29:61:5f:33:7d:b3:74:97:3b:
            3a:f3:11:01:7c:b8:37:a8:8c:72:81:ee:92:fd:91:
            8a:11:b3:b3:02:b4:97:d5:f8:1b:91:54:7e:15:49:
            26:6d
        Exponent: 65537 (0x10001)
X509v3 extensions:
    X509v3 Basic Constraints: critical
        CA:TRUE, pathlen:0
    X509v3 Key Usage: critical
        Certificate Sign, CRL Sign
    X509v3 Subject Key Identifier: 
        CE:D1:31:DE:CF:E3:E2:BC:6C:73:3D:55:F0:88:53:0A:F1:DC:31:14
    X509v3 Authority Key Identifier: 
        0.
Signature Algorithm: sha1WithRSAEncryption
     0b:7b:28:f6:b9:1e:6e:ec:53:6a:c5:77:db:c5:3f:5e:1d:ab:
     e5:43:73:eb:52:24:af:39:2b:aa:a3:f6:34:e1:92:4b:3b:5e:
     b6:1
```

Answer (score 13):

It means that the CA key you are using doesn't have a subjectKeyIdentifier set.

In your example you are creating the authorityKeyIdentifier using a reference to ca which doesn't have subjectKeyIdentifier set yet.

If you change your code a to:

```
ca.add_extensions([
  OpenSSL.crypto.X509Extension("basicConstraints", True,
                               "CA:TRUE, pathlen:0"),
  OpenSSL.crypto.X509Extension("keyUsage", True,
                               "keyCertSign, cRLSign"),
  OpenSSL.crypto.X509Extension("subjectKeyIdentifier", False, "hash",
                               subject=ca),
  ])
ca.add_extensions([
  OpenSSL.crypto.X509Extension("authorityKeyIdentifier", False, "keyid:always",issuer=ca)
  ])
```

then it works.